# Converting from 0-0 0 0:0:33 to Seconds

Tags: sql

How do I convert my ride_length from this (0-0 0 0:0:33) to time?

Comment: What is your DBMS? String and Datetime functions differ greatly for different products.

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the time from the string using `SUBSTRING`

```
select CAST(REVERSE(substring(reverse('0-0 0 0:0:33'),0,7)) as time);

--If the data is same in this column use
select CAST(REVERSE(substring(reverse(ride_length),0,7)) as time); 

-- Best way
select CAST(REVERSE(substring(reverse('0-0 0 0:0:33'),0,charindex(' ',reverse('0-0 0 0:0:33')))) as time);

select CAST(REVERSE(substring(reverse(ride_length),0,charindex(' ',reverse(ride_length)))) as time);
```

Substring: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp
Charindex: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_charindex.asp

For MSSQL server

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: I'll try this thank you. I'm a little confused about why you wouldn't use CONVERT? And What does CAST do?

Comment: CAST and CONVERT function are very similar with minor difference. 
CAST: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp
CONVERT: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp
Difference between CAST and CONVERT: http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/software-technology/difference-between-cast-and-convert-2/#:~:text=CAST%20and%20CONVERT%20are%20two,one%20data%20type%20to%20another.&text=The%20CAST%20function%20is%20used,types%20at%20the%20same%20time.